# Megillas Esther Online text Shiur ideally with Rashi's commentary

Tags: commentaries, rashi, megillat-esther

Looking for a Megillas Esther text shiur with Rashi's commentary similar to Rabbi Gordon from Chabad.org for Chumash.
He goes through each Pasuk and then explains Rashi's commentary inside  but for the Megillah.
Thanks